# Fit outer div with to its content

Tags: html, css

In the example below how can I make the `outer` div with to fit the width of the boxes? All the solutions I have found say that the outer div must have `display: inline-block` but that doesn't seem to work if the child elements are also `inline-block`. Is there any other solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/45fexke7/

In short the `outer` div should be centered inside `wrapper` and have the width of the inner content.

EDITED:

This must be responsive! `wrapper` has a fixed width in the example but let's say it's `width: 100%`. It should display as many boxes as it can in one row but it there is a remaining space the boxes must be centered.

Comment: how about we center all the inner divs - some thing like this https://jsfiddle.net/45fexke7/1/

Comment: @HudhaifaYoosuf that's an option but I don't want the last boxes to be in center if they don't fill the row...

Comment: how about you set a fixed with to the outer, you obviously know the inner values 220px* 3 for 3 boxes + margin. can be the width for the outer

Comment: @HudhaifaYoosuf It must be responsive...

Comment: then best way is to make the inner div width in % , as per my knowledge

Comment: this should go as your expectation https://jsfiddle.net/45fexke7/4/

Comment: @HudhaifaYoosuf I'm afraid I didn't explain the problem well enough... Please see the updated question

Comment: give me a feed back for the answer below. let me see what i can do to improve it

Comment: it doesn't make sense, if you say "the inner content has to display as many boxes as it can", it means the inner content has to follow the width of the wrapper, as the outer has no width, then it is valid to set width for outer too (or simply remove it), it means your wrapper will be always filled up. thus the "outer div should be centered inside wrapper" is invalid too

Comment: @SKLTFZ no sum of boxes width != width of wrapper in all cases.

Comment: @KingJulien  you means the outer should wrap the rendered inner content (for example inner content reference the 800px width wrapper, and the inner content contains divs which is 600, thus you expected the outer should has 600 width and centered within wrapper). i think it can only be done in javascript (or some advance CSS, which i dont know)

Comment: I have revised the code and it should implement what i have said in the above comment, and as i mentioned i have added scripts to handle it. See if it can solve the problem. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can set display property for the outer class as [flex](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp).
with these additional properties.

https://jsfiddle.net/sambit_satpathy/h2gurosb/

```
 #outer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: black;
  width:100%;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
```

Comment: please note "In short the outer div should be centered inside wrapper and have the width of the inner content." in the problem

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#outer {
  /*   display: inline-block; */
  text-align: left;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
}
.inner {
  width: 33%;
  height: 200px;
  /*   margin: 5px; */
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <div id="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Nope.. `outer` should not have `width: 100%;`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that, but you need script to help render the outer's width. note that your inner contains margin thus you need to handle it in the script too.

```js
$(function ($) {
  var longestWidth = 0;
  var sumwidth = 0;
  $("#outer").children().each(function() {
        var child = $(this);
    if(sumwidth + child.width()+10<800)
        sumwidth+=child.width()+10;
    else 
    {
      if(longestWidth<sumwidth)
      longestWidth = sumwidth+10;
      console.log(longestWidth);
      sumwidth = 0;
    }
      
    });
    $("#outer").width(longestWidth);
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  background-color: red;
  text-align:center;
}

#outer {
 
  background-color: black;
  display: inline-block;
}

.inner {
  width: 220px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: green;
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should go as your expectation.

Changes the inner div width to a percentage and changed margins.

```
  .inner {
   margin-left: 6px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 32%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: green;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}

#outer {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: black;
}

.inner {
   margin-left: 6px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 32%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: green;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <div id="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: `.innser` shoud not have a percent width. There must be as many columns of boxes as possible. According to how wide the `wrapper` is. But the entire column of boxes, which is `outer` must be centered as well, because the sum of the boxes width may not be equal to `wrapper`'s width.

Comment: Yes so? The `wrapper` width is unknown.

Comment: you have defined wrapper width as 800px;  . ?